# Why does class member variable partially work After global class array constructor executing?

Tags: c++

I declare and define a global class array `Test arrs[] ={ {"1"}, {"2"} };`
I make sure that constructor of every element in the array has executed.
My Test class declaration is in the file Test.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    string from, suffix;
    Test(string s);
};
```

my Test class implementation is in the file Test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
Test::Test(string from) {
    from = "abc";
    suffix = "123";
    cout << "Test constructor from = " << from << " suffix = " << suffix << endl;// diagnostic
}
```

My test file for Test class is in the main.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
Test arrs[] ={ {"1"}, {"2"} };

int main() {
    cout <<" cons[0] test from: " << arrs[0].from << endl;
    cout <<" cons[0] test suffix: " << arrs[0].suffix << endl;
    cout <<" cons[1] test from: " << arrs[1].from << endl;
    cout <<" cons[1] test suffix: " << arrs[1].suffix << endl;
}
```

The test result is:

```
Test constructor from = abc suffix = 123
Test constructor from = abc suffix = 123
cons[0] test from:
cons[0] test suffix: 123
cons[1] test from:
cons[1] test suffix: 123
```

Why `from` member variable is empty? I have assigned it to "abc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method parameter is shadowing the actual member variable 'from'. Change you code to:

```
#include "test.h"
Test::Test(string variable_not_called_from) {
    from = "abc";
    suffix = "123";
    cout << "Test constructor from = " << from << " suffix = " << suffix << endl;// diagnostic
}
```

Then you will see the result you expect.